# Redirection http to https not working with AWS EC2 and CodeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After I have installed the SSL in AWS EC2 the following URLs:

- https://www.abcd.com
- https://abcd.com
- www.abcd.com
- http://www.abcd.com

... are redirecting to https://www.abcd.com and are working perfect.

But http://abcd.com is not redirected.

How can I fix this?

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abcd\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abcd.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Tested [here](https://htaccess.mwl.be/).